# difference in 'category-".$row['id'].".php' and 'category-.php".$row['id']."'

Tags: php

I am confused and couldn't figure out the difference between these two lines!!

```
echo "<li><a href='category-".$row['id'].".php' >".$row['name']."</a></li>";
```

The first one echos categories I displayed in a home page. It works fine and I don't have to create the category.php file.

```
echo "<li><a href='category-.php".$row['id']."' >".$row['name']."</a></li>";
```

But the second code it tells me file doesn't exist.

So my question is, why the first code doesn't require the file but the second code does?

Comment: I imagine there's a lot more to this scenario than you're telling us, but in the first case you'll get filenames like `category-123.php` and the second you'll get filenames like `category-.php123`.

Comment: It's hard to understand your question because there is more than you tell us. In it's current form, it's not possible to answer it properly in my eyes. Please consider to add more information to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense why the second file doesn't exist - look at the filename you're constructing:

```
category-.php<int>
```

Unless you have a file called `category-` with an extension that matches `\.php\d+`, this doesn't make any sense.

The first line makes perfect sense:

```
"category-".$row["id"].".php"
```

This would result in filenames like `category-1.php`, or `category-2.php`.

Comment: This was from a script I found. So the owner didn't create the category.php file, instead, he redirected the data (values) that come from here `echo "<li><a href='category-".$row['id'].".php' >".$row['name']."</a></li>"; `

in ".htaccess" file. So, it looked like this : RewriteRule category-(.*)\.php$ buy.php?cat=$1

I think I would just go with this: `echo "<li><a href='category.php?cat=".$row['id']."' >".$row['name']."</a></li>";`

Thanks for quick responce guys!

Answer (score 0):

It just looks like in the second one you have put the .php extension in the wrong place for the file.  I'm sure you are trying to get category-ROWVALUE.php, just move the .php after the row id and then they will work the same.

Hope that helps